# Compiz and drag behavior after "snapping"

Tags: compiz

Big question..
Does anybody has problems while dragging a snapped window from the corners (aero-snap-style?)

I have this very very annoying problem ..and also some comparable problems with dragging in the EXPO view.. at the second click to a window to drag it moves exponentially to the mouse.

Comment: I have this problem too, where the windows don't snap back properly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this. Fire up CCSM (thats compiz config settings manager, you might need to install it via the Software Center).
Go to Snapping Windows -> Behaviour and untick Edge Resistance.